# Regarding Ampere's Circuital Law

Tags: electromagnetism, mathematical-physics, magnetic-fields, vector-fields

If I am to show that Ampere's Circuital law holds true for any arbitrary closed loop in a plane normal to the straight wire, with its validity already established for the closed loop being a circle of radius $r$, and if I were to go about it in the following manner:

1. Assume coordinates $(x_1,x_2)$ in the plane.
2. Assume that a homeomorphism $f:X\longrightarrow Y$, where $X=(x_1,x_2)$ and $Y=(x'_1,x'_2)$, exists such that the closed curve taken is mapped onto a circle of radius $r$ and the magnetic (vector) field $\vec{B}$ is mapped onto the field $\vec{B'}$.

Thus, the dot product within the integral is preserved, i.e. $\vec{B}\cdot \vec{dl}=\vec{B'}\cdot\vec{dl'}$. The total current flowing through the wire remains the same, so the original integral is equated with $\mu_0 I_{eq}$

$\oint_C \vec{B}\cdot \vec{dl}=\oint_{S^1}\vec{B'}\cdot \vec{dl'}=\mu_0I_{eq}$

So my question is: is this valid?

---

EDIT: Proof that the dot product will be preserved is as follows-
taking $\vec{u}$ with components $u^{\alpha}$ and $\vec{v}$ with components $v^{\beta}$, $<\vec{u},\vec{v}>=g_{\alpha\beta}u^{\alpha}v^{\beta}=\Lambda^{\alpha'}_{\alpha}\Lambda^{\beta'}_{\beta}g_{\alpha'\beta'}\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\alpha'}u^{\alpha'}\Lambda^{\beta}_{\beta'}v^{\beta'}=g_{\alpha'\beta'}u^{\alpha'}v^{\beta'}=<\vec{u'},\vec{v'}>$

Although this isn't mathematically rigorous, I hope that it suffices.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Are you asking if the following is true: $\oint_C \textbf{B} \cdot d \textbf{r} = \mu_0 I$ for any circle $C$ centered at the origin implies $\oint_P \textbf{B} \cdot d \textbf{r} = \mu_0 I$ for any closed path $P$ enclosing the origin?

Comment: @Nathan Sorry for the lack of clarity. I believe the statement you have written is true and I have attempted to demonstrate it. I am asking whether there are any flaws in the demonstration or not, i.e., whether I have made any mistakes or not. Just because a series of steps lead to the desired result doesn't always imply that the steps themselves are correct, so I'm just being sure...

Comment: I think when you are doing the change of variable you are forgetting the determinent of the jacobian of your mapping though. Indeed a bigger circle should lead to stronger magnetic fields(provided currents pass across its whole surface). Indeed, $det(J)$ represents the enclosed surfaces ratio defined by the 2 curves .

Comment: @RonanTarikDrevon I thought that the dot product would eliminate the need for the Jacobian determinant... thank you for that. The size of the circle is irrelevant here, no? Since we're only concerned with the closed integral?

Comment: I think you misunderstand this theorem : It states that the circulation of the magnetic field H along a closed contour C is equal to the currents passing through the surface enclosed by this contour. Consequently, the size of the circle does actually matter and  what you are trying to establish can only be true for isosurface contours provided the integrated current I is the same. This Ampere's law is actually the same thing as maxwell equation $\nabla\times\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{j}$ which is as far as I know a fundamental principle

Comment: @RonanTarikDrevon I'm not saying that the magnetic field doesn't change with the choice of the closed curve. What I'm saying is that the closed integral over any closed curve doesn't change. That's why $\oint_{C}\vec{B}\cdot\vec{dl}=\mu_0 I_{eq}$ for any closed curve $C$ if $I_{eq}$ remains the same, no?

Comment: Alright if you assume that $I_{eq}$ remains the same the dot product is indeed conserved but the reason is because the field B is actually decreased. Though I do not understand where is the proof that the dot product is preserved..

Comment: @RonanTarikDrevon I've added what I think is a valid proof to the question.